# SignalA library for the SignalR server using protocol version 1.0?

Tags: android, signalr

which signalA android library i can use for the SignalR server which is using protocol version 1.0?

Comment: from nuget console 'Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR'

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately does SignalA not support protocol version 1.0.